# str_replace (package stringr) cannot replace brackets in r?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a string, say

```
 fruit <- "()goodapple"
```

I want to remove the brackets in the string. I decide to use stringr package because it usually can handle this kind of issues. I use :

```
str_replace(fruit,"()","")
```

But nothing is replaced, and the following is replaced:

```
[1] "()good"
```

If I only want to replace the right half bracket, it works:

```
str_replace(fruit,")","") 
[1] "(good"
```

However, the left half bracket does not work:

```
str_replace(fruit,"(","")
```

and the following error is shown:

```
Error in sub("(", "", "()good", fixed = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE) : 
 invalid regular expression '(', reason 'Missing ')''
```

Anyone has ideas why this happens? How can I remove the "()" in the string, then?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Escaping the parentheses does it...

```
str_replace(fruit,"\\(\\)","")
# [1] "goodapple"
```

---

You may also want to consider exploring the [**"stringi" package**](http://www.rexamine.com/resources/stringi/), which has a similar approach to "stringr" but has more flexible functions. For instance, there is `stri_replace_all_fixed`, which would be useful here since your search string is a fixed pattern, not a regex pattern:

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_fixed(fruit, "()", "")
# [1] "goodapple"
```

---

Of course, basic `gsub` handles this just fine too:

```
gsub("()", "", fruit, fixed=TRUE)
# [1] "goodapple"
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works for your exact problem, but not for the more general problem:

```
my_fruits <- c("()goodapple", "(bad)apple", "(funnyapple")
str_replace(my_fruits,"\\(\\)","")
## "goodapple"  "(bad)apple", "(funnyapple"
```

This is because the regex exactly matches a "(" followed by a ")".

Assuming you care only about bracket pairs, this is a stronger solution:

```
str_replace(my_fruits, "\\([^()]{0,}\\)", "")
## "goodapple"   "apple"       "(funnyapple"
```

Answer (score 2):

Building off of MJH's answer, this removes all ( or ):

```
my_fruits <- c("()goodapple", "(bad)apple", "(funnyapple")
str_replace_all(my_fruits, "[//(//)]", "")

[1] "goodapple"  "badapple"   "funnyapple"
```