# Problem escaping the parentheses when using str_replace

Tags: r, tidyverse

My problem seems similar to this:  [str_replace (package stringr) cannot replace brackets in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065378/str-replace-package-stringr-cannot-replace-brackets-in-r)

But hopefully somebody can help me.

Here's some sample data:

```
a<- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<- c("Home", "Rehab", "Home", "Discharged home or self-care (routine discharge) AHR", "Home")
DF<- data.frame(a,b)
```

There's hundreds of rows, and i'm trying to go through and replace all the "Discharged home or self-care (routine discharge) AHR" with "Home".  When I try:

```
library(tidyverse)  
DF<-DF%>%mutate(b=str_replace(b,"Discharged home or self-care (routine discharge) AHR","Home"))
```

Nothing happens.  If i try similar code to replace all the "Home"'s with something else for instance.... works fine:

```
DF<-DF%>%mutate(b=str_replace(b,"Home","House"))
```

So I figure it has something to do with the parentheses, but I'm lost on escaping it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a fixed match, we can use `replace` from `base R` along with `==`

```
library(dplyr)
DF%>%
   mutate(b= replace(b,
     b == "Discharged home or self-care (routine discharge) AHR","Home"))
```

---

Or in `str_replace`, specify the `fixed` because the `()` are regex metacharacters for capturing groups and by default it is in regex mode .

```
library(stringr)
DF %>%
  mutate(b=str_replace(b,
     fixed("Discharged home or self-care (routine discharge) AHR"),"Home"))
```

TO literally evaluate the `(`, we need to escape (`\\(`) or place it inside square brackets or with `fixed` wrapper

```
DF%>%
   mutate(b=str_replace(b,
    "Discharged home or self-care \\(routine discharge\\) AHR","Home"))
```